# MySql database connection issues in play framework (driver not found)

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

So I have tried using the stock Play! 2.2 configuration for the MySql database connection. Unfortunately the guides out there are less than helpful when using the stock database (h2) alongside a MySql. SO, I coded a separate model to handle the MySql connection. It works intermittently, and I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work all of the time.

this is the "connect" function

```
String sourceSchema = "db";
    String databaseHost = "host";
    String databaseURLSource = "jdbc:mysql://" + databaseHost + "/" + sourceSchema;
    String databaseUserIDSource = "userid";
    String databasePWDSource = "password";

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURLSource,
                databaseUserIDSource, databasePWDSource);

        return true;

    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.error("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

All of my credentials are correct (here obviously they are changed) Next, in my lib folder, I have the

```
 mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
```

in place.

Next, in my Build.scala, I have this under appDependencies:

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.21"
```

when I try to validate the connection, using:

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    return conn != null;
}
```

The connection fails (intermittantly) and then gives me:

```
SQLException: Before start of result set
```

and sometimes:

```
SQLException: No Suitable driver found for mysql ...
```

This is how my query is executed:

```
String qs = String.format("SELECT * FROM community_hub.alert_journal LIMIT("+ from +","+ to +")");
```

```
    String qscount = String.format("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM community_hub.alert_journal");

try {

        if (isConnected()) {

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            //obtain count of rows
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(qscount);
            //returns  the number of pages to draw on index
            int numPages = returnPages(rs1.getInt("count"),rpp);
            NumPages(numPages);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qs);

            while (rs.next())
            {
                AlertEntry ae = new AlertEntry(
                        rs.getTimestamp("date"),
                        rs.getString("service_url"),
                        rs.getString("type"),
                        rs.getString("offering_id"),
                        rs.getString("observed_property"),
                        rs.getString("detail")
                );

                list.add(ae);
            }

            rs.close();
            disconnect();

        } else {
            System.err.println("Connection was null");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does the mysql error tell you anything?

the first error "SQLException: Before start of result set" looks like its incomplete. Maybe the error log contains the full message or you can

the second one "SQLException: No Suitable driver found for mysql" clearly indicates a classpath issue.

usually connection pools like c3p0 or BoneCP recommed to use a validation query to determine if a connection is valid (something like "select 1" for mysql). That may help to make sure the connection is ok and not rely on the driver?